# Is it possible to perform an API call in a delegate method that returns a BOOL?

Tags: ios, parsing, delegates, objective-c-blocks

Strange title, I know, but here is the quickest way to explain my issue. The Parse service has a prebuilt Sign Up controller for letting new users sign up for whatever service you may have. There is no way to edit it's implementation, you can only handle events in it's delegate methods. So I can't just place this in the IBAction of the "Sign Up" button. What I want to do is, when a user touches "Sign up", is that I need to make a call to some API to check if something exists or not, and then if it does already exist then don't let the user sign up. Here is the delegate method meant to handle validation when the button is pressed:

```
// Sent to the delegate to determine whether the sign up request should be submitted to the server.
- (BOOL)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController shouldBeginSignUp:(NSDictionary *)info {
```

Here is what I'm trying to place in it:

```
[self processJSONDataWithURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.someapi.com/api/profile.json?username=%@",username] andBlock:^(NSData *jsonData) {

    NSDictionary *attributes = [jsonData objectFromJSONData];

    // Check to see if username has data key, if so, that means it already exists
    if ([attributes objectForKey:@"Data"]) {
        return NO; // Do not continue, username already exists
    // I've also tried:
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ return NO; } );
    }
else
        return YES; //Continue with sign up
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ return YES; } );
}];
```

I get errors when I try to return anything, though. When I just do a straight return YES, "^(NSData *jsonData)" is underlined in yellow and I get "Incompatible block pointer types sending BOOL (^)NSData *_*strong to parameter of type void(^)NSData **_strong".

Basically, in there any way to make an API call in this method to check something and then return YES or NO depending on the result?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()^ twice???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You are invoking an asynchronous method that is using the block as a callback.  The `processJSON…` method is invoked and immediately returns from the call.  After it runs in the background the block is invoked.  You cannot "return" from within the block.  The method was popped off the stack and returned some time previously.

You need to re-architect the logic of this.  Invoking a refresh on the main queue is in the right direction.

Comment: +1, but another way to look at it is: *Yes. You can make all the API calls you want, provided that they're synchronous. What you can't do is put a synchronous call on hold while you wait for an asynchronous operation to get back to you.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[self processJSONDataWithURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.someapi.com/api/profile.json?username=%@",username] andBlock:^(NSData *jsonData) {

    NSDictionary *attributes = [jsonData objectFromJSONData];
    BOOL status=YES; 
    // Check to see if username has data key, if so, that means it already exists
    if ([attributes objectForKey:@"Data"]) {
        status=NO; // Do not continue, username already exists

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(callDelegate:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:status] waitUntilDone:YES];
}];

-(void)callDelegate:(NSNumber*) status
 {
   BOOL returnStatus = [status boolValue];

   //now retutn returnStatus to your delegate.
 }
```

But this is not the right way to do it, you gotta change the logic you have written to support asynchronous communication. You could consider mine, only if you want to do it your way.